# USA resident minor traveling Jamaica— USA — Jamaica

Tags: children, minors, us-residents, jamaican-citizens

My 3 year old son is in the country of his birth (Jamaica)but he is also a USA resident I want to spend a week with him then send him back to his mom can I buy a two way ticket when he is coming to America?

Comment: What do you mean by "USA resident"? Do you mean he is a US permanent resident (a.k.a. green card holder)? If so, he is supposed to be living in the US. Is he doing that?

Comment: Would someone be traveling with him? Because many (all?) airlines wouldn't take a child that young without a companion.

Comment: Do you actually mean “he is also a US citizen”, maybe? If either parent is a US citizen, chances are he is also (though the rules are complex).